# Google Gson issue with deserializing

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I have a Java class:

```
public class Object1 {
    private int field1;
    private String field2;
    private Object2 object2;
    private boolean field3;
}
```

I've saved some Object1 instance as JSON string using Gson:

```
    String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(object1, Object1.class);
```

And then I added new String field to Object1 class:

```
public class Object1 {
    private int field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field4;
    private Object2 object2;
    private boolean field3;
}
```

And now I can't to deserialize json string to Object1 instance using method:

```
Object1 obj1 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Object1.class);
```

Because of Gson throws exception:

> System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 444 path $.c
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)

But why? I have JSON string without one field and it can't to be a problem. Why I can't deserialize it?

Comment: Post the json you want to deserialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out problem was in obfuscation.

If you're not use @SerializedName annotation result JSON can be like that:

> {"a":3436213,"b":"some string","c":{.............},"d":true}

We didn't use it because of it isn't DTO. In this case we using JSON just to store some unimportant internal data. But it was very funny lesson for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT`

`field4` in your json string is not of type String, use a Json to POJO generator to create a proper object.

I like to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/